# Como registrar corretamento um componente importado com Vue.js?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue.js-2

> erro:  Unknown custom element:  - did you register the component correctly? For recursive components, make sure to provide the "name" option
>   Estou tentando registar um componente contendo um form mas dá esse erro acima.

```
 import formClienteComponent from "./partials/formClienteComponent";
    export default {
      components: {
        'form-cliente': formClienteComponent
      },
```

Componente.vue  //código completo

```
 <template>
      <div>
        <div class="element-wrapper">
          <div class="element-actions">
            <a class="btn btn-success btn-large" href="#">
              <i class="os-icon os-icon-ui-22"></i>
              <span>Salvar</span>
            </a>
          </div>
          <h1 class="element-header">Novo Cliente</h1>

          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-12">
              <div class="element-wrapper">
                <div class="element-box">

                 <form-cliente></form-cliente>

                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </template>

    <script>
    import { TheMask } from "vue-the-mask";
    import formClienteComponent from "./partials/formClienteComponent";
    export default {
      components: {
        'form-cliente': formClienteComponent
      },
      computed: {
        bancos() {
          return this.$store.state.bancos.items.data;
        }
      },

      data() {
        return {
          errors: {}
        };
      },
      components: { TheMask },

      methods: {
        submitForm() {
          this.$store
            .dispatch("storeClientes", this.cliente)
            .then(() => this.$router.push({ name: "admin.clientes" }))
            .catch();
        }
      }
    };
    </script>
```

formClienteComponent.vue

```
<template>
  <div>
    <form id="formValidate" novalidate="true" @submit.prevent="submitForm">
      <h5 class="form-header">Form Validation</h5>
      <div class="form-desc">
        Validation of the form is made possible using powerful validator plugin for bootstrap.
        <a
          href="http://1000hz.github.io/bootstrap-validator/"
          target="_blank"
        >Learn more about Bootstrap Validator</a>
      </div>

      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-6">
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for>Nome</label>
            <input
              name="nome"
              v-model="cliente.nome"
              class="form-control"
              data-error="Insira um nome válido"
              placeholder="Insira um nome válido"
              required="required"
              type="text"
            />
            <div class="help-block form-text with-errors form-control-feedback"></div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-4">
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for>CPF</label>
            <input
              v-model="cliente.cpf"
              v-mask="'###.###.###-##'"
              name="cpf"
              class="form-control"
              data-error="Digite um CPF Válido"
              placeholder="Digite um CPF Válido"
              required="required"
              type="text"
            />
            <div class="help-block form-text with-errors form-control-feedback"></div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-2">
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for>CEP</label>
            <input
              v-model="cliente.cep"
              v-mask="'#####-###'"
              class="form-control"
              data-error="CEP"
              placeholder="Insira um CEP válido"
              required="required"
              type="text"
            />
            <div class="help-block form-text with-errors form-control-feedback"></div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-4">
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for>Endereço</label>
            <input
              v-model="cliente.endereco"
              name="endereco"
              class="form-control"
              data-error="Digite um Endereço"
              placeholder="Digite um Endereço"
              required="required"
              type="text"
            />
            <div class="help-block form-text with-errors form-control-feedback"></div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-1">
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for>Número</label>
            <input
              v-model="cliente.numero"
              name="numero"
              class="form-control"
              data-error="Digite um numero"
              placeholder="Nº"
              required="required"
              type="text"
            />
            <div class="help-block form-text with-errors form-control-feedback"></div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-3">
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for>Bairro</label>
            <input
              v-model="cliente.bairro"
              name="bairro"
              class="form-control"
              data-error="Digite um Bairro"
              placeholder="Digite um Bairro"
              required="required"
              type="text"
            />
            <div class="help-block form-text with-errors form-control-feedback"></div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-2">
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for>Cidade</label>
            <input
              v-model="cliente.cidade"
              name="cidade"
              class="form-control"
              data-error="Digite uma cidade"
              placeholder="Digite uma cidade"
              required="required"
              type="text"
            />
            <div class="help-block form-text with-errors form-control-feedback"></div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-2">
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for>UF</label>
            <select
              class="form-control"
              v-model="cliente.estado"
              name="estado"
              data-error="Digite um Estado"
              placeholder="Digite uma Estado"
              required="required"
            >
              <option value>Selecione</option>
              <option value="AC">Acre</option>
              <option value="AL">Alagoas</option>
              <option value="AP">Amapá</option>
              <option value="AM">Amazonas</option>
              <option value="BA">Bahia</option>
              <option value="CE">Ceará</option>
              <option value="DF">Distrito Federal</option>
              <option value="ES">Espirito Santo</option>
              <option value="GO">Goiás</option>
              <option value="MA">Maranhão</option>
              <option value="MS">Mato Grosso do Sul</option>
              <option value="MT">Mato Grosso</option>
              <option value="MG">Minas Gerais</option>
              <option value="PA">Pará</option>
              <option value="PB">Paraíba</option>
              <option value="PR">Paraná</option>
              <option value="PE">Pernambuco</option>
              <option value="PI">Piauí</option>
              <option value="RJ">Rio de Janeiro</option>
              <option value="RN">Rio Grande do Norte</option>
              <option value="RS">Rio Grande do Sul</option>
              <option value="RO">Rondônia</option>
              <option value="RR">Roraima</option>
              <option value="SC">Santa Catarina</option>
              <option value="SP">São Paulo</option>
              <option value="SE">Sergipe</option>
              <option value="TO">Tocantins</option>
            </select>

            <div class="help-block form-text with-errors form-control-feedback"></div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-6">
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for>Telefone</label>
            <input
              class="form-control"
              placeholder="Telefone"
              required="required"
              v-model="cliente.telefone"
              v-mask="'(##) #####-####'"
              name="telefone"
            />
            <div
              class="help-block form-text text-muted form-control-feedback"
            >Minimum of 6 characters</div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-6">
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for>Confirm Password</label>
            <input
              class="form-control"
              data-match-error="Passwords don't match"
              placeholder="Confirm Password"
              required="required"
              type="text"
            />
            <div class="help-block form-text with-errors form-control-feedback"></div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <fieldset class="form-group">
        <legend>
          <span>Bancos</span>
        </legend>

        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-sm-4">
            <div class="form-group">
              <label for>Banco</label>
              <select name="banco" class="form-control" v-model="cliente.banco">
                <option value>Selecione o Banco</option>
                <option
                  v-for="banco in bancos"
                  :key="banco.id"
                  :value="banco.id"
                >{{ banco.codigo }}-{{ banco.nome }}</option>
              </select>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-sm-4">
            <div class="form-group">
              <label for>Agência</label>
              <input
                class="form-control"
                data-match-error="Agência"
                name="agencia"
                v-model="cliente.agencia"
                placeholder="Agência"
                required="required"
                type="text"
              />
              <div class="help-block form-text with-errors form-control-feedback"></div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-sm-4">
            <div class="form-group">
              <label for>Conta</label>
              <input
                class="form-control"
                data-match-error="Conta"
                placeholder="Nº da Conta"
                name="conta"
                v-model="cliente.conta"
                required="required"
                type="text"
              />
              <div class="help-block form-text with-errors form-control-feedback"></div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-sm-4">
            <div class="form-group">
              <label for>Banco</label>
              <select name="banco2" class="form-control" v-model="cliente.banco2">
                <option value>Selecione o Banco</option>
                <option
                  v-for="banco in bancos"
                  :key="banco.id"
                  :value="banco.id"
                >{{ banco.codigo }}-{{ banco.nome }}</option>
              </select>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-sm-4">
            <div class="form-group">
              <label for>Agência</label>
              <input
                class="form-control"
                data-match-error="Agência"
                name="agencia2"
                v-model="cliente.agencia2"
                placeholder="Agência"
                required="required"
                type="text"
              />
              <div class="help-block form-text with-errors form-control-feedback"></div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-sm-4">
            <div class="form-group">
              <label for>Conta</label>
              <input
                class="form-control"
                data-match-error="Conta"
                placeholder="Nº da Conta"
                name="conta2"
                v-model="cliente.conta2"
                required="required"
                type="text"
              />
              <div class="help-block form-text with-errors form-control-feedback"></div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-sm-4">
            <div class="form-group">
              <label for>Banco</label>
              <select name="banco3" class="form-control" v-model="cliente.banco3">
                <option value>Selecione o Banco</option>
                <option
                  v-for="banco in bancos"
                  :key="banco.id"
                  :value="banco.id"
                >{{ banco.codigo }}-{{ banco.nome }}</option>
              </select>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-sm-4">
            <div class="form-group">
              <label for>Agência</label>
              <input
                class="form-control"
                data-match-error="Agência"
                name="agencia3"
                v-model="cliente.agencia3"
                placeholder="Agência"
                required="required"
                type="text"
              />
              <div class="help-block form-text with-errors form-control-feedback"></div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-sm-4">
            <div class="form-group">
              <label for>Conta</label>
              <input
                class="form-control"
                data-match-error="Conta"
                placeholder="Nº da Conta"
                name="conta3"
                v-model="cliente.conta3"
                required="required"
                type="text"
              />
              <div class="help-block form-text with-errors form-control-feedback"></div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </fieldset>

      <fieldset class="form-group">
        <legend>
          <span>Section Example</span>
        </legend>
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-sm-6">
            <div class="form-group">
              <label for>First Name</label>
              <input
                class="form-control"
                data-error="Please input your First Name"
                placeholder="First Name"
                required="required"
                type="text"
              />
              <div class="help-block form-text with-errors form-control-feedback"></div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-sm-6">
            <div class="form-group">
              <label for>Last Name</label>
              <input
                class="form-control"
                data-error="Please input your Last Name"
                placeholder="Last Name"
                required="required"
                type="text"
              />
              <div class="help-block form-text with-errors form-control-feedback"></div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-sm-6">
            <div class="form-group">
              <label for>Date of Birth</label>
              <input
                class="single-daterange form-control"
                placeholder="Date of birth"
                type="text"
                value="04/12/1978"
              />
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-sm-6">
            <div class="form-group">
              <label for>Twitter Username</label>
              <div class="input-group">
                <div class="input-group-prepend">
                  <div class="input-group-text">@</div>
                </div>
                <input class="form-control" placeholder="Twitter Username" type="text" />
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for>Date Range Picker</label>
          <input class="multi-daterange form-control" type="text" value="03/31/2017 - 04/06/2017" />
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <label>Example textarea</label>
          <textarea class="form-control" rows="3"></textarea>
        </div>
      </fieldset>
      <div class="form-check">
        <label class="form-check-label">
          <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" />I agree to terms and conditions
        </label>
      </div>
      <div class="form-buttons-w">
        <button class="btn btn-primary disabled" type="submit">Submit</button>
      </div>
    </form>
  </div>
</template>


<script>
export default {
  props: {
    cliente: {
      require: false,
      type: Object,
      default: () => {
        return {
            id:"",
          nome: "",
          cpf: "",
          cep: "",
          endereco: "",
          numero: "",
          bairro: "",
          cidade: "",
          estado: "",
          telefone: "",
          banco: "",
          agencia: "",
          conta: "",
          banco2: "",
          agencia2: "",
          conta2: "",
          banco3: "",
          agencia3: "",
          conta3: ""
        };
      }
    },
    updating: {
      require: false,
      type: Boolean,
      default: false
    }
  },
  computed: {
    bancos() {
      return this.$store.state.bancos.items.data;
    }
  },
  methods: {
    submitForm() {
      const action = this.updating ? "updateCliente" : "storeClientes";
      this.$store
        .dispatch(action, this.cliente)
        .then(() => this.$router.push({ name: "admin.clientes" }))
        .catch();
    }
  }
};
</script>

<style scoped>
</style>
```

Comment: Podes mostrar o conteúdo desse `./partials/formClienteComponent`? deves usar `.vue` no nome do ficheiro...

Comment: Sim, acabei de colocar!

Comment: O primeiro bloco de código que tens aqui na pergunta é o quê?

Comment: e o componente principal, e o segundo é o partial. No caso o formClienteComponent.vue é importado dentro do Componente.vue

Comment: Então tens componentes aninhados com o mesmo nome? ou seja tens `<form-cliente>` dentro de `<form-cliente>`?

Comment: Não, form-cliente é um aliás de formClienteComponent. Estou tentando importar formClienteComponent.vue    >>>>>  Componente.vue